# Host nodejs app in which source files are inside a directory

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, package.json, heroku-cli

I want to host a nodejs project from github. I am using Heroku cloud platform. Heroku requires **package.json** file at **root directory** of github, but it is present inside a folder on github. So, how can i host it? How can i solve this root directory problem? I cannot add any extra files and folder at root directory of github.

Suppose a folder **Project** on github:

```
Project
    |__public
    |__views
    |__.env
    |__.gitignore
    |__.app.json
    |__index.js
    |__package.json
    |__package-lock.json
    |__procfile
    |__README.md
    |__test.js
```

Comment: Put another `package.json` at the root that redirects appropriate commands (install, build, start) to your project?

Comment: Thank you, but is there any other way? I do not want to change folder structure.

Comment: That wouldn't require changing the folder structure, just adding that one extra file.

Comment: On github root directory, it will show a **Project folder** and a **Package.json file**. I do not  want this. Is there any other way?

Comment: That's not the same thing as changing the folder structure, though. And no - the Heroku Node buildpack requires a package file at the repo root: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#activation.

Comment: *"I cannot add any extra files"* - it might be helpful to say *why*, but, per the link I shared above, if that *is* the case then you can't deploy your current repo directly to Heroku.

Comment: _"I cannot add any extra files"_  **because** the root directory of github will change. In future more things will come at github's root directory.

Comment: _"Put another package.json at the root that redirects appropriate commands (install, build, start) to your project?"_  I performed this. Now, root directory has Project and package.json folder and file respectively. How can specify node.js path because it is not fetching node.js from Project folder.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "node.js path". That's not a responsibility of the package file, the node runtime needs to be installed in the environment (on Heroku, it's in the buildpack).

Comment: I am getting 503 error with this repository . Repository contain -folder(which contain node.js file, package.json, procfile )  and - package.json file in root directory. But with other repo. in which all are at root directory works file.